# Empirical Mode Decomposition(EMD) + CNN for time series forecasting

Tags: regression, time-series, python, convolution, decomposition

I'm currently working on a time series project, and I intend to employ the EMD+CNN technique for forecasting the output. Upon applying EMD to the training data, I obtained a total of 14 Intrinsic Mode Functions (IMFs). Consequently, I constructed my CNN neural network with dimensions (30100, 20, 14, 1), with 20 representing the window size. However, I encountered an issue when attempting to decompose the test data using EMD, as it produced only 11 IMFs. This inconsistency caused an error when trying to execute the CNN model.

I have two questions: Is there a method to enforce a consistent number of IMFs during the EMD decomposition process? If not, is there an automated way to select the most significant IMFs?

Please note that I am utilizing the EMD-signal library in Python.

Thank you.